# linq crosstab with dynamic columns

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following Lists of objects and I use linq join them using a Left Outer Join, after that I need to expand some dynamic rows into columns using linq but that is where I have an issue.

```
private List<ClasslistDto> GetClassList()
        {
            return new List<ClasslistDto>
            {
                new ClasslistDto{StudentID = "0101", StudentName = "Student 1", ClassID = "1", ClassName="Class 2", Sex = "M", ResStatus="Day"},
                new ClasslistDto{StudentID = "0102", StudentName = "Student 2", ClassID = "1", ClassName="Class 2", Sex = "M", ResStatus="Day"},
                new ClasslistDto{StudentID = "0103", StudentName = "Student 3", ClassID = "1", ClassName="Class 2", Sex = "F", ResStatus="Day"},
                new ClasslistDto{StudentID = "0104", StudentName = "Student 4", ClassID = "1", ClassName="Class 2", Sex = "M", ResStatus="Day"},
                new ClasslistDto{StudentID = "0105", StudentName = "Student 5", ClassID = "1", ClassName="Class 2", Sex = "F", ResStatus="Day"},
                new ClasslistDto{StudentID = "0106", StudentName = "Student 6", ClassID = "1", ClassName="Class 2", Sex = "M", ResStatus="Day"},
                new ClasslistDto{StudentID = "0107", StudentName = "Student 7", ClassID = "1", ClassName="Class 2", Sex = "M", ResStatus="Day"},
                new ClasslistDto{StudentID = "0108", StudentName = "Student 8", ClassID = "1", ClassName="Class 2", Sex = "F", ResStatus="Day"},
                new ClasslistDto{StudentID = "0109", StudentName = "Student 9", ClassID = "1", ClassName="Class 2", Sex = "F", ResStatus="Day"}
            };
        }
private List<ExamTypeDto> GetExams()
        {
            return new List<ExamTypeDto>
            {
                new ExamTypeDto{ExamTypeID="EX01", ExamType = "Test 1", MaxMark = 10},
                new ExamTypeDto{ExamTypeID="EX02", ExamType = "Project", MaxMark = 20},
                new ExamTypeDto{ExamTypeID="EX03", ExamType = "Test 2", MaxMark = 20},
                new ExamTypeDto{ExamTypeID="EX04", ExamType = "MidTerm", MaxMark = 50},
                new ExamTypeDto{ExamTypeID="EX05", ExamType = "Exams", MaxMark = 100}
            };
        }

private List<StudentMarkDto> GetStudentMarks()
        {
            return new List<StudentMarkDto>
            {
                new StudentMarkDto{StudentID = "0101", ClassID = "1", ExamTypeID="EX01", Mark=8},
                new StudentMarkDto{StudentID = "0101", ClassID = "1", ExamTypeID="EX02", Mark=17},
                new StudentMarkDto{StudentID = "0101", ClassID = "1", ExamTypeID="EX03", Mark=12},
                new StudentMarkDto{StudentID = "0101", ClassID = "1", ExamTypeID="EX04", Mark=38},
                new StudentMarkDto{StudentID = "0101", ClassID = "1", ExamTypeID="EX05", Mark=97},
                new StudentMarkDto{StudentID = "0102", ClassID = "1", ExamTypeID="EX01", Mark=9},
                new StudentMarkDto{StudentID = "0102", ClassID = "1", ExamTypeID="EX02", Mark=13.7},
                new StudentMarkDto{StudentID = "0102", ClassID = "1", ExamTypeID="EX03", Mark=15},
                new StudentMarkDto{StudentID = "0102", ClassID = "1", ExamTypeID="EX04", Mark=47},
                new StudentMarkDto{StudentID = "0102", ClassID = "1", ExamTypeID="EX05", Mark=91},
                new StudentMarkDto{StudentID = "0103", ClassID = "1", ExamTypeID="EX01", Mark=10},
                new StudentMarkDto{StudentID = "0103", ClassID = "1", ExamTypeID="EX02", Mark=14},
                new StudentMarkDto{StudentID = "0103", ClassID = "1", ExamTypeID="EX03", Mark=15},
                new StudentMarkDto{StudentID = "0103", ClassID = "1", ExamTypeID="EX04", Mark=50},
                new StudentMarkDto{StudentID = "0103", ClassID = "1", ExamTypeID="EX05", Mark=86},
                new StudentMarkDto{StudentID = "0104", ClassID = "1", ExamTypeID="EX01", Mark=5},
                new StudentMarkDto{StudentID = "0104", ClassID = "1", ExamTypeID="EX02", Mark=10},
                new StudentMarkDto{StudentID = "0104", ClassID = "1", ExamTypeID="EX03", Mark=15},
                new StudentMarkDto{StudentID = "0104", ClassID = "1", ExamTypeID="EX04", Mark=25},
                new StudentMarkDto{StudentID = "0104", ClassID = "1", ExamTypeID="EX05", Mark=59},
                new StudentMarkDto{StudentID = "0105", ClassID = "1", ExamTypeID="EX01", Mark=8},
                new StudentMarkDto{StudentID = "0105", ClassID = "1", ExamTypeID="EX02", Mark=13},
                new StudentMarkDto{StudentID = "0105", ClassID = "1", ExamTypeID="EX03", Mark=10.5},
                new StudentMarkDto{StudentID = "0105", ClassID = "1", ExamTypeID="EX04", Mark=39},
                new StudentMarkDto{StudentID = "0105", ClassID = "1", ExamTypeID="EX05", Mark=75},
                new StudentMarkDto{StudentID = "0106", ClassID = "1", ExamTypeID="EX01", Mark=8},
                new StudentMarkDto{StudentID = "0106", ClassID = "1", ExamTypeID="EX02", Mark=14},
                new StudentMarkDto{StudentID = "0106", ClassID = "1", ExamTypeID="EX03", Mark=15},
                new StudentMarkDto{StudentID = "0106", ClassID = "1", ExamTypeID="EX04", Mark=40},
                new StudentMarkDto{StudentID = "0106", ClassID = "1", ExamTypeID="EX05", Mark=65},

                new StudentMarkDto{StudentID = "0107", ClassID = "1", ExamTypeID="EX01", Mark=10},
                new StudentMarkDto{StudentID = "0107", ClassID = "1", ExamTypeID="EX02", Mark=14},
                new StudentMarkDto{StudentID = "0107", ClassID = "1", ExamTypeID="EX03", Mark=15},
                new StudentMarkDto{StudentID = "0107", ClassID = "1", ExamTypeID="EX04", Mark=50},
                new StudentMarkDto{StudentID = "0107", ClassID = "1", ExamTypeID="EX05", Mark=86},
                new StudentMarkDto{StudentID = "0108", ClassID = "1", ExamTypeID="EX01", Mark=10},
                new StudentMarkDto{StudentID = "0108", ClassID = "1", ExamTypeID="EX02", Mark=14},
                new StudentMarkDto{StudentID = "0108", ClassID = "1", ExamTypeID="EX03", Mark=15},
                new StudentMarkDto{StudentID = "0108", ClassID = "1", ExamTypeID="EX04", Mark=50},
                new StudentMarkDto{StudentID = "0108", ClassID = "1", ExamTypeID="EX05", Mark=86},
                new StudentMarkDto{StudentID = "0109", ClassID = "1", ExamTypeID="EX01", Mark=10},
                new StudentMarkDto{StudentID = "0109", ClassID = "1", ExamTypeID="EX02", Mark=14},
                new StudentMarkDto{StudentID = "0109", ClassID = "1", ExamTypeID="EX03", Mark=15},
                new StudentMarkDto{StudentID = "0109", ClassID = "1", ExamTypeID="EX04", Mark=50},
                new StudentMarkDto{StudentID = "0109", ClassID = "1", ExamTypeID="EX05", Mark=86}

            };
        }
```

I use the left outer join

```
var result = (from s in classlist
                          join m in studentMarks on s.StudentID equals m.StudentID
                          into st_def
                          from m in st_def.DefaultIfEmpty()
                          join e in exams on m.ExamTypeID equals e.ExamTypeID into ex_def
                          from e in ex_def.DefaultIfEmpty()
                          select new ManualEntryAllDto
                          {
                              StudentID = s.StudentID,
                              StudentName = s.StudentName,
                              ExamTypeID = m.ExamTypeID,
                              ExamName = e.ExamType,
                              MaxMark = e.MaxMark,
                              Marks = m.Mark
                          });
```

I get the results that appear
[image]

I however need to flatten it further so I get results like this

```
StudentID | StudentName | Test 1 | Project | Test 2 | MidTerm | Exams
0101      | Student 1   | 8      | 17      | 12     | 38      | 97
0102      | Student 2   | 9      | 13.7    | 15     | 47      | 91
...
...
```

In case `GetStudentMarks()` return an empty list, we still need it to return

```
StudentID | StudentName | Test 1 | Project | Test 2 | MidTerm | Exams
0101      | Student 1   | 0      | 0       | 0      | 0       | 0
0102      | Student 2   | 0      | 0       | 0      | 0       | 0
...
...
```

The Other caveat is `GetExams()` may return N number of rows
I found a function here on stackoverflow to flatten a list but I am not able to use it to get the desired results

```
public static dynamic[] ToPivotArray<T, TColumn, TRow, TData>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source,
    Func<T, TColumn> columnSelector,
    Expression<Func<T, TRow>> rowSelector,
    Func<IEnumerable<T>, TData> dataSelector)
        {

            var arr = new List<object>();
            var cols = new List<string>();
            String rowName = ((MemberExpression)rowSelector.Body).Member.Name;
            var columns = source.Select(columnSelector).Distinct();

            cols = (new[] { rowName }).Concat(columns.Select(x => x.ToString())).ToList();


            var rows = source.GroupBy(rowSelector.Compile())
                             .Select(rowGroup => new
                             {
                                 Key = rowGroup.Key,
                                 Values = columns.GroupJoin(
                                     rowGroup,
                                     c => c,
                                     r => columnSelector(r),
                                     (c, columnGroup) => dataSelector(columnGroup))
                             }).ToArray();


            foreach (var row in rows)
            {
                var items = row.Values.Cast<object>().ToList();
                items.Insert(0, row.Key);
                var obj = GetAnonymousObject(cols, items);
                arr.Add(obj);
            }
            return arr.ToArray();
        }

        private static dynamic GetAnonymousObject(IEnumerable<string> columns, IEnumerable<object> values)
        {
            IDictionary<string, object> eo = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, object>;
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < columns.Count(); i++)
            {
                eo.Add(columns.ElementAt<string>(i), values.ElementAt<object>(i));
            }
            return eo;
        }
```

Any pointers will be great

Comment: C# is a language of types. What type do you want the final result to be?

Comment: a dynamic type of some known and unknown properties, known properties is 
`StudentID | StudentName` and unknown properties which is the number of exam types in the exam definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a variation of an extension method I have for pivoting `IEnumerable<T>` that returns a `List<dynamic>` instead of the original `DataTable`:

```
public static class IEnumerableExt {
    // pivot an IEnumerable<T> to a new DataTable
    // over field creates new column names
    // value field is value for new columns
    // By fields are row ids and grouping key
    public static dynamic PivotOverWithBysToDynamic<TRow>(this IEnumerable<TRow> rows, string OverColName, string WithValueName, params string[] ByRowNames) {
        var res = new List<dynamic>();
        if (rows.Count() > 0) {
            var rowg = rows.GroupBy(row => ByRowNames.Select(f => row.GetValue(f)).ToList(),
                                    row => new { Over = row.GetValue(OverColName).ToString(), With = row.GetValue(WithValueName) },
                                    Make.IESequenceEqual<object>());

            foreach (var rg in rowg) {
                var rgKey = rg.Key.ToList();
                var newr = new ExpandoObject();
                var newrMap = (IDictionary<string, object>)newr;
                for (int j1 = 0; j1 < ByRowNames.Length; ++j1)
                    newrMap[ByRowNames[j1]] = rgKey[j1];
                foreach (var r in rg)
                    newrMap[r.Over] = r.With;
                res.Add(newr);
            }
        }

        return res;
    }
}
```

This code depends on a lot of other extension methods in order to make getting the values out of the original object properties somewhat efficient (by caching functions that return the value for a property to minimize reflection overhead) and to make comparing sequences easier:

```
public static class Make {
    public static IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<T>> IESequenceEqual<T>() => new IEnumerableSequenceEqualityComparer<T>();

    private class IEnumerableSequenceEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<T>> {
        public bool Equals(IEnumerable<T> x, IEnumerable<T> y) =>
            Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y) || (x != null && y != null && (x.SequenceEqual(y)));

        public int GetHashCode(IEnumerable<T> items) {
            var hc = new HashCode();
            foreach (var item in items)
                hc.Add(item);
            return hc.ToHashCode();
        }
    }
}

//***
// Enhanced Dictionary that auto-creates missing entries with seed lambda based on key
// ala auto-vivification in Perl
//***
public class KeySeedFnDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue> {
    Func<TKey, TValue> seedFn;

    public KeySeedFnDictionary(Func<TKey, TValue> pSeedFn) : base() {
        seedFn = pSeedFn;
    }
    public KeySeedFnDictionary(Func<TKey, TValue> pSeedFn, IDictionary<TKey, TValue> d) : base() {
        seedFn = pSeedFn;
        foreach (var kvp in d)
            Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
    }

    public new TValue this[TKey key] {
        get {
            if (!TryGetValue(key, out var val))
                base[key] = (val = seedFn(key));

            return val;
        }
        set => base[key] = value;
    }
}

public static class MemberInfoExt {
    public static Func<object, object> GetValueFunc(this MemberInfo member) {
        switch (member) {
            case FieldInfo mfi:
                return mfi.GetValue;
            case PropertyInfo mpi:
                return mpi.GetValue;
            case MethodInfo mi:
                return (object srcObject) => mi.Invoke(srcObject, null);
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("MemberInfo must be of type FieldInfo, PropertyInfo or MethodInfo", nameof(member));
        }
    }
}

public static class TypeExt {
    public static MemberInfo GetPropertyOrField(this Type t, string memberName, BindingFlags bf = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance) =>
        t.GetMember(memberName, bf).Where(mi => mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field || mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property).Single();

}

public static class ObjectExt {
    static KeySeedFnDictionary<(Type t, string m), MemberInfo> memberInfoCache = new(tm => tm.t.GetPropertyOrField(tm.m));
    static KeySeedFnDictionary<(Type t, string m), Func<object, object>> getFnCache = new(tm => memberInfoCache[(tm.t, tm.m)].GetValueFunc());

    public static TRes GetValue<TRes>(this object obj, string memberName) {
        var getFn = getFnCache[(obj.GetType(), memberName)];
        return (TRes)getFn(obj);
    }
    public static object GetValue<T>(this T obj, string memberName) => ((object)obj).GetValue<object>(memberName);
}
```

In order to handle the possibility of `GetStudentMarks()` returning an empty list, you must change the query to join with the marks last:

```
var result = (from s in classlist
              from e in exams
              join m in studentMarks on new { s.StudentID, e.ExamTypeID } equals new { m.StudentID, m.ExamTypeID } into mj
              from m in mj.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new ManualEntryAllDto {
                  StudentID = s.StudentID,
                  StudentName = s.StudentName,
                  ExamTypeID = e.ExamTypeID,
                  ExamName = e.ExamType,
                  MaxMark = e.MaxMark,
                  Marks = m?.Mark ?? default
              });
```

Once you have the data (essentially left join plus right join) you can pivot it:

```
var ans = result.PivotOverWithBysToDynamic("ExamName", "Marks", new[] { "StudentID", "StudentName" });
```

Comment: That's some brilliant idea, it works and I need to continue studying it to fully understand. Thank you @NetMage for your time and effort

Comment: @Tonto As I said, I already had most of this lying around (in my LINQPad extensions). The tricky part was the query :) In any case, feel free to ask any questions. It is a lot easier if you work with dynamic data in a `DataTable` or `ExpandoObject` as the source as well.